# Hive XML Serdie xpath retreiving null values

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, hive

```
I have the sample XML file, Sorry for editing the sample xml missed some tags 



<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <wd:File xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
 <wd:Report_Entry>
 <wd:All_Candidate_Job_Profiles wd:Descriptor="Manager I">
 <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e83ebdbd2a0a013fcbb5009a49e9d9d4</wd:ID>
 <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">US-100017363</wd:ID>
 </wd:All_Candidate_Job_Profiles>
 <wd:All_Companies_as_Text>Xyz, Inc.</wd:All_Companies_as_Text> 
 <wd:All_Watched_Companies>0</wd:All_Watched_Companies>
 </wd:Report_Entry>
 <wd:Report_Entry>
 <wd:All_Candidate_Job_Profiles wd:Descriptor="Manager II">
 <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e83ebdbd2a0a013fcbb5009a49e9d9d4</wd:ID>
 <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">US-100017363</wd:ID>
 </wd:All_Candidate_Job_Profiles>
 <wd:All_Companies_as_Text>abc, Inc.</wd:All_Companies_as_Text> 
 <wd:All_Watched_Companies>0</wd:All_Watched_Companies>
 </wd:Report_Entry>
 </wd:File>
```

I am trying to load the data using the following query:

```
CREATE external TABLE ww_hr_dl_staging_hiring.recruiting_candidates_serdie(
        All_Candidate_Job_Profiles array<string>,
        All_Companies_as_Text string,
        All_Watched_Companies string
        )
        ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
        WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
        'column.xpath.All_Companies_as_Text'='wd:File/wd:Report_Entry/*
        [local-name()=\"wd:All_Companies_as_Text\"]/text()',
        'column.xpath.All_Watched_Companies'='wd:File/wd:Report_Entry/* 
        [local-name()=\"wd:All_Watched_Companies\"]/text()' 
        )
        STORED AS
        INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
        OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
        TBLPROPERTIES (
        'xmlinput.start'='<wd:File xmlns',
        'xmlinput.end'='</wd:File>'
        );
```

Loading data from hdfs using load data inpath 'path' into 'tablename'

Up on selecting the data from the query i am getting null values

select * from ww_hr_dl_staging_hiring.recruiting_candidates_serdie;

OK
NULL    NULL

```
My output should retreive

Manager I Xyz, Inc 0
Manager II abc inc 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the XPATH you are using is not matching with any element. The correct xpath should be.

> //*[local-name(.)="All_Companies_as_Text"]/text()
>
> //*[local-name(.)="All_Watched_Companies"]/text()

This is the working code

```
CREATE external TABLE temp.recruiting_candidates_serdie(
        All_Companies_as_Text string,
        All_Watched_Companies string
        )
        ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
        WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
        'column.xpath.All_Companies_as_Text'='//*[local-name(.)="All_Companies_as_Text"]/text()',
        'column.xpath.All_Watched_Companies'='//*[local-name(.)="All_Watched_Companies"]/text()' 
        )
        STORED AS
        INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
        OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
        location '/tmp/test_xml/table'
        TBLPROPERTIES (
        'xmlinput.start'='<wd:File xmlns',
        'xmlinput.end'='</wd:File>'
        )
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurang. Can you explain the change within the code?

Comment: it's just how this serde understands xpath when you are using `namespace`. one more thing I have done is used `relative xpath` (starting with double // rather than /)

Comment: Will it work if i want to retrieve the value from this tag All_Candidate_Job_Profile? <wd:All_Candidate_Job_Profiles wd:Descriptor="Manager III, Talent Acquisition - Human Resources">

Comment: This code is retreiving all the values as a single string.The output is displayed a follows:    <string>values of all_companie_as_text</string> <string>values of all_watched_companies></string>    But i need output as : xyz inc ,0                       next row (abc inc,0)

Comment: I have tested an it wors as expected. make sure you are using the xpath correctly.  I form the xpath bases on given sample, if actual file is different it might work

Comment: I just edited the xml and added the missing tags. When added the xpath i see null  and rest values are populated as     NULL    <string>Walmart, Inc.US VISION, Walmart, Inc., and JC PENNEYWalmart,</string> <string><000></string>

Comment: I also want to retreive value for All_Candidate_Job_Profiles but when adding the xpath for the required column i am getting Null populated. Am i missing anything over here?